# Run C daemon in iOS app

Tags: ios, c, iphone, xcode, daemon

I want to run daemon inside my iOS app that was originally written in C for linux. I can understand that I can't run daemon on background and make it available to all other apps - at least not without jailbreak. I do not want to do that. What I want is to take an existing daemon and use it solely inside my app and only when it is on foreground. The point is 1) to save some work as the daemon is already written and 2) keep it compatible with future updates because the daemon is open source so when developers make changes but do not change API I have just little work with any update. How to do that? Is it possible to take daemon code and run it in some separate process? Thank you for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing about the same things. For my case, I have real daemon that of course runs only on jail broken iOS devices. However, since to debug the daemon code is very difficult, I developed a fake daemon which runs as a "legal" iOS program.

There are two points that needs to be considered.

(1) how to start fake daemon

Real iOS device prevents sand box apps to create process; I mean fork() fails.
So, the fake daemon should be implemented as a thread.
I'm using Thread(target:selector:object:) but you can use POSIX pthread_create(), too.
Note real daemon starts up very differently. So, you need some modification around daemon start up code. If your daemon internally creates processes w/ fork(), porting efforts would get very large.

(2) how to communicate with daemon

For my case, real daemon communicates with app thru UNIX socket. So, the fake daemon does the same.
I create socket communication path in app's /tmp as follows.

```
NSString *sockPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/tmp/sockPath"];
sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_un sa = {0};
sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(sa.sun_path, [sockPath UTF8String]);
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
....
```

Pretty much regular way to use UNIX socket. Then both app and fake daemon communicate thru this socket.

Communication between apps and daemons are dependent on the daemons. You need to consider how to minimize porting efforts for your daemons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This daemon communicates through port so it should works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *possible* approach to turning a daemon into something that can be used in an iOS application without launching a separate process:

- Recompile as a dylib, renaming the main function to, for example main_daemon

This gives you a function `main_daemon(int argc, char **argv)` that you can use to launch the daemon - you could run it from a thread, for example.

A list of *some* of the issues to address would be:

- no `fork()` - so if it uses processes for service handling, this would need to be replaced by threads.
- configuration files - they would need to be within the app's container
- pid files - their creation is not needed
- communication channels - they would need to be within the app's container
- signal handling - this would have to be replaced by some other mechanism
- termination handling - again, this would have to *not* call `exit()` or other things

This list is in no way complete, it's just a few things that came immediately to mind.

It's probably not a trivial amount of work - it depends on the code and complexity, and every time you upgrade the daemon for your app, you're going to have to re-check all the changes to ensure they work.

Comment: Than you very much. Why .dylib? Is it somehow important to have it dynamically loaded?

Comment: Just a force of habit - I tend to avoid direct linking because I can, in theory, drop in a replacement or testing dummy without recompilation. One thing I did not mention here was *licensing*, which could have implications at the legal end of things, especially if the daemon code is under the GPL license.